# Connection Reset Exception for Socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have Code with simple pass the message

```
public class Servlet_New {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{

        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(5001);
        Socket s=ss.accept();
        InputStream is=s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os=s.getOutputStream();
        String str="Hello";
        os.write(str.getBytes());
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
   }}
```

And Client Side

```
public class Client_New {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket s=new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),5001);
         InputStream is=s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os=s.getOutputStream();
        DataInputStream br=new DataInputStream(is);
        String str;
        str = br.readUTF();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error "+ex.getMessage());
    }

}}
```

And I am getting Connection Reset error when i am reading from the stream in client side

Comment: There is a huge different between [`OutputStream.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-byte:A-) and [`DataOutputStream.writeUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Does that mean that Thai error occurred due to different methods of stream ? @Edwardth

Comment: Hard to see why else he would have mentioned it. Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

If you read with `readUTF()` you need to write with `writeUTF()`.

The Javadoc makes this pretty clear.